# クロスドメイン通信でhttp status code が0

Tags: javascript

## 前提

- XMLHTTPRequestで別ドメイン（Bサイトという）にアクセスする処理
- Bサイトは、認証機能がありRequest Headerにトークンを渡す必要がある
- 認証された場合、http status code 200とレスポンスが返ってくる
- 認証されなかった場合、http status code 401が返ってくる

## 質問

BサイトへXMLHTTPRequestでアクセスし、認証されなかった場合、
Javascriptでhttp statusを取得すると status code は 0 になっています。
なぜ、0が返ってくるのでしょうか。
chrome 開発者ツールのnetworkは、401を返しています。

https://teratail.com/questions/21794
で同様の質問がありましたが、解決されていないため、質問させていただきます。

### プレフライトリクエスト

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 実際のリクエスト　(status 401が返ってきている)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### Javascript　（status 0になっている）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

サーバー側の設定を変更することで解決できました。
サーバはAmazon API Gatewayを使用しており、カスタムオーソライザーで弾かれた場合、Access-Control-Allow-Origi‌​nヘッダーがレスポンスに付与されないため‌​、問題が生じていたようです。

以下のフォーラムで議論されています:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228211&start=25&tstart=0

フォーラムの回答で先月このユースケースに対応した旨の記載があったため、以下ドキュメントを参考に設定を試したところ、認証エラー時に401を取得することができました。
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/apigateway/latest/developerguide/customize-gateway-responses.html#supported-gateway-response-types

Answer (score 5):

[RFC7235 3.1.  401 Unauthorized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1)から引用します。

> The 401 (Unauthorized) status code indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.  **The server generating a 401 response MUST send a WWW-Authenticate header field** (Section 4.1) containing at least one challenge applicable to the target resource.

と401レスポンスには`WWW-Authenticate`ヘッダーが必須です。しかし画像を見る限り`WWW-Authenticate`が含まれていません。このためブラウザーは認証処理をできずに困ったためエラーと見なしたのだと思います。

エラー時に`XMLHttpRequest.status`が`0`を返すのはmaotさんの回答の通りです。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。サーバ側の設定変更が必要になりそうですね。サーバ側の担当者と明日以降に直接会話することになりましたので、原因と対応方法がわかりましたら、ここに報告します。

Answer (score 0):

ブラウザの仕様かもしれません。
[MDNのリファレンス](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status)で以下のように記載されています。

> Before the request is complete, the value of status will be 0. It is worth noting that browsers report a status of 0 in case of XMLHttpRequest errors too.

```
リクエストが完了する前はstatusは0である。XMLHttpRequestのエラーもまたブラウザは0をレポートする。
```

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest Standard では "netword error" なるものが定められています。

> 1. If the send() flag is unset, return.
> 2. If response is a [network error](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-network-error), run the request error steps for event error and exception NetworkError.
>
> (引用元: [4.5.6. The send() method - XMLHttpRequest Standard](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#handle-errors))
>   (引用元-日本語訳: [4.5.6. send() メソッド - XMLHttpRequest Standard （日本語訳）](https://triple-underscore.github.io/XHR-ja.html#handle-errors))

リンク先の Fetch Standard を参照すると、"netword error" の際には `status` に 0 が代入されるとあります。

> A response whose type is "error" is known as a **network error**.
>   A network error is a response whose status is always `0`, status message is always the empty byte sequence, header list is always empty, body is always null, and trailer is always empty.
>   (引用元: [2.2.6. Responses - Fetch Standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-network-error))
>   (引用元-日本語訳: [2.2.6. 応答 - Fetch Standard （日本語訳）](https://triple-underscore.github.io/Fetch-ja.html#concept-network-error))

"netword error" になる条件はいくつかありそうですが、軽く調べてみたところでは次のパターンがあります。

- `XMLHttpRequest#abort()` した
- HTTPリクエストが終了した
- `XMLHttpRequest#open()` 実行後、変数 `response` に有効な値が代入されなかった(変数 `response` の初期値は "netword error")

Re: tetsuya さん